# Beamer class: text height too large for height of footline and headline with tikz pictures

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, header-footer

I tried to recreate my university powerpoint template which includes images as headline and footline banner (beamer class, no predefined theme, xelatex). It seemed easier to place image plus text with tikz. When placing text in frames, text starts within the headline and violates the footline (positioning t or b). My MWE draws a box with `\textheight`to illustrate the problem.

[image]

I found this code snippet which should somehow increase the height of the footline but it didn't solve the problem. I hope someone can help me out. Thanks!

```
\makeatletter
    \patchcmd{\beamer@calculateheadfoot}{\advance\footheight by 4pt}{\advance\footheight by 20pt}{}{}
\makeatother
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[
        presentation,
        %handout,
        11pt,
        aspectratio=43, % 4:3, 128mm:96mm
        table,
        usepdftitle=false,
]{beamer}

% Packages
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, shapes.arrows, arrows.meta, positioning, fit, calc, backgrounds, patterns, 3d}

% Lengths
\newlength{\myLeftMargin}
\newlength{\myLeftMarginText}
\newlength{\myRightMargin}
\newlength{\myRightMarginText}

\setlength{\myLeftMargin}{0.019685\paperwidth}
\setlength{\myLeftMarginText}{0.0909\paperwidth}
\setlength{\myRightMargin}{\myLeftMargin}
\setlength{\myRightMarginText}{\myLeftMarginText}

\setbeamersize{text margin left=\myLeftMarginText}
\setbeamersize{text margin right=\myRightMarginText}
\setbeamersize{sidebar width left=0pt}

% Headline
\makeatletter
    \patchcmd{\beamer@calculateheadfoot}{\advance\footheight by 4pt}{\advance\footheight by 20pt}{}{}
\makeatother

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
        \node[anchor=north west, inner sep=0pt] at ($(current page.north west)+(0,0)$) (nodeHeadlineBar){
            \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth, height=0.15\paperheight]{example-image}
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
        \node[anchor=west, inner sep=0pt] at ($(nodeHeadlineBar.west)+(\myLeftMargin,0)$){
            \insertframetitle
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
        \node[anchor=south west, inner sep=0pt] at ($(current page.south west)+(0,0)$) (nodeFootlineBar){
            \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth, height=0.05\paperheight]{example-image}
        };
        \node[anchor=east, inner sep=0pt] at ($(nodeFootlineBar.east)+(-\myRightMargin,0)$){
            \insertframenumber\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
    \section{Example 1}
    \begin{frame}[b]{\secname}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[red] (0,0) rectangle (\textwidth,\textheight);
            \draw[red] (0,\textheight) -- (\textwidth,0)
                       (0,0) -- (\textwidth, \textheight);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{frame}
    \section{Example 2}
    \begin{frame}[t]{\secname}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[red] (0,0) rectangle (\textwidth,\textheight);
            \draw[red] (0,\textheight) -- (\textwidth,0)
            (0,0) -- (\textwidth, \textheight);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```